# How identify numbers in Chrome Extension using Uipath?

Tags: uipath

I have this screenshot in a Chrome extension where numbers appear randomly.

When numbers are like 0.001, 0.006, 0.008, 0.001092 (format like 0.00XXXX) then go to actions that I programmed.

However when numbers are 0.02, 0.06, 0.4, 4.2 then it continues waiting and checking until next number have the first condition (0.00XXXX).

[image]

I’m a newbie with Uipath. Could you give me a image of how could be structured the flowchart in uipath workspace? How can I program that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I quite understand the question, but if you're wanting to create a workflow based on the result of the 'Double' you've obtained.
Then just create an If like below:
[image]